# Iteratively open image with increasing ID number as a file name in pyhon

Tags: python

I've got an image database with a set of images named [frame01.png, frame02.png, ..., frameN.png].
My directory path is ./img, and iteratively I'd like to read one by one, do some image processing until reaching the last one. Since I'm not familiar with strings concatenation in python, what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would say globbing is your friend... https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: `fnames = sorted(glob.glob("/your/path/*.png"))`

Comment: Hello, Miguel, and welcome to [SO]. SO is a question-and-answer site. Your post, while full of relevant detail, is still missing the essential element of a good [SO] post: a question. What, precisely, are you asking?

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks for the heads up, I've already edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_names = os.listdir('path_to_folder/')
```

should give you a list of all you files.
To read them you can have:

```
for file_name in file_names:
   read_and_process_image('path_to_folder/' + file_name)
```

Then inside `read_and_process_image`:

```
import matplotlib.image

def read_and_process_image(path):
   read_img = matplotlib.image.imread(path) # or whatever you use to read the image
   # process read_img
```

Alternatively, you could have:

```
import glob

for image_path in glob.glob("path_to_your_image*.png"):
    image = matplotlib.image.imread(image_path) # or whatever you use to read the image
    # process your image
```

If you are just looking for a quick way to create the list with this particular names:

```
[ 'frame' + "%02d" % (i,) + '.png'  for i in range(1, MAX_NUM)]
```

If your last image is 20 then replace MAX_NUM with 20 + 1 applies for any other number x, x + 1. 
How/what you use to read the files depends on you. You can use `matplotlib.image` as in the examples or whatever works for you.